# Simple read of child nodes from Firebase DB not working

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON Tree in the Firebase Realtime database. I just want to iterate and read through all of the items under `questions`. I think I am doing something silly wrong.

Under the "My App" - I have a "questions" branch and saving a bunch of data under it. Below is the tree and my code. In the code I point out the part that is crashing. Circled in red below are what I am trying to read.

[image]

```
public void readfromFireDB() {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("questions");

    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            **THIS IS THE ERROR, ques comes back as NULL**
            Question ques = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);

            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });

}
```

**This Issue**: `ques` in `onDataChanged()` comes back as a null reference. May be I am not accessing the children under `questions` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `ValueEventListener` you're accessing the *list of questions*, not an individual question.

To access each individual question, you'll need to loop over the snapshot:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot questionSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Question ques = questionSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
        String key = questionSnapshot.getKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Going to be reading the documentation once more clearly.